# Find mode using Javascript with 2 rules based on my code

Tags: javascript

so this is what I've achieved so far

```
 function arrayMode(sequence) {
  var arr= [];
  var mostFreq = 1;

  for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    arr[i] = 0;

  for(var i = 0 ; i < sequence.length; i++)
    arr[sequence[i]]++;

  for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    if( arr[i] > arr[mostFreq])
      mostFreq = i;
  } 

  return mostFreq;
}
```

so the scope for my case are

- The sequence value is >= 1 and <=10
- The sequence length is > 0
- The sequence is an array of integer

Example 1
Input : sequence = [1, 10, 10]
Output : 10

Example 2
Input : sequence = [1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
Output : 3

It seems easy, I've tried to figure out but I cant find where is the mistake in my code, It's seems legit for me

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give a description? Example input / output would be welcome to be able to give any meaningful help.

Comment: This doesn't explain what your input is or what expected results are  or what your code is doing differently than expected. Please read [ask]

Comment: Your last loop should run from 1 to 10, not to sequence.length

Comment: @bali182 code updated

Comment: @charlietfl added input output example

Comment: @Kevin based on your example output, mostFreq should be arr[i], not i

Comment: Note `arr` does not have it's first element defined. Start your for-loop with `var i = 0`. Arrays starting index is `0`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yeah i realized this, but i just want to make this make sense for human(especially me), because the value start from 1 so i just want to leave arr[0] undefined

Comment: what if there are more than one max sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Maxim Krizhanovsky, the last loop should go from 1 to 10 instead of to sequence.length.  Here is the working code

```
function arrayMode(sequence) {
   var arr= [];
   var mostFreq = 1;

   for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
      arr.push(0);

  for(var i = 0 ; i < sequence.length; i++)
      arr[sequence[i]]++;

  for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
     if( arr[i] > arr[mostFreq])
          mostFreq = i;
  } 

  return mostFreq;
}
```

The output is 10 and 3 respectively to your input.

Comment: just realized that tho hahaha

Comment: How is this different? What the did OP do wrong? It would be helpful to have some explanation here.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek should be i <= 10 not i < 10